# oracle query to remove extra spaces after word and no spaces after a dot in a string

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I want an oracle query that will handle two things:

1) Only ONE space after any word. Remove any extra spaces if any after any word in the string.

2) Do not want to see any spaces if any,  after any "dot or comma or colon or semi-colon" in the string. ZERO spaces after `".` or `,` or `;` or `:"`

example:

```
'My  name is Pramod.  I am writing a query,  Today is AUG 16TH: 2019;  X11.'
```

Requested output:

```
'My name is Pramod.I am writing a query,Today is AUG 16TH:2019;X11.'
```

Note: There are two spaces after `My` and two spaces after `I`,`;`,`:` and `,`.

Comment: What went wrong with your previous question with the same problem you posted several minutes ago?

Comment: Well what have you tried?

Comment: I had to change the requirement. Can you help me with the query here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regexp_replace:

```
FSITJA@db01> select regexp_replace('My  name is Pramod. I    am writing   .   a query, Today is AUG 16TH:   2019; X11.  abc', '([,;:. ]){1} +', '\1')
  2      from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('MYNAMEISPRAMOD.IAMWRITING.AQUERY,TODAYISAUG16TH:2019;X
----------------------------------------------------------------------
My name is Pramod.I am writing .a query,Today is AUG 16TH:2019;X11.abc
```

Comment: You could add the space to the bracketed expression, then you won't need alternation and the function call becomes much simpler.

Comment: You're right, that went over my head. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
...
regexp_replace(input_string, '( |\.|,|:|;) +', '\1')
...
```

The stuff in parentheses in the second argument (the regular expression) is an *alternation* - it matches exactly one of the five characters space, period, comma, colon or semicolon. (Period must be escaped, of course.) You can include any punctuation characters there. The stuff in parentheses is also a *subexpression* which can be referenced by a *backreference* in the third argument to the function.

Find and read the documentation for Oracle `regexp_replace()` if you are unfamiliar with any of these concepts.

Comment: BINGOOOOOOOOOO.

Comment: @PramodKumar - This can be written more simply along the lines in Francisco Sitja's answer, modified according to my comment below his answer. That answer uses a *character class* instead of an alternation (you still need the parentheses around it to create a subexpression, just like he showed). The advantage of the alternation is that it's more flexible - you can also eliminate all spaces after specific text fragments longer than just one character, if needed.